# How to force one element to have the same width as another? (phantom?)

Tags: spacing

(Context: I have a case where I'm using MathJax and an HTML table with cells for various expressions that I want to align, so I can't use an `align` environment.)

Is there a way to force one element to have the same width as another? I know about `\phantom`, so for example these fragments should have the same width:

```
a+x^2+b 

a+\phantom{x^2}+b
```

But what if I want to show `a+0+b` instead of `a+x^2+b`, and I want `0` to be centered in an hbox with the same width as `x^2`?

Comment: note that most tex solutions are going to involve the measuring of a box but that won't work in mathjax, mathjax specific solutions are off-topic though as mathjax doen't use tex.

Comment: I would like to voice my continued disagreement with the mathjax-is-off-topic philosophy of this site.

Comment: if you comment there it just pings me, and the discussion about that was mostly before I was active on the site. You could raise it again on meta but I don't suppose the issues have really changed. see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/mathjax-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

You can centre the 0 in a box the size of the omitted expression

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a+x^2+b $

$a+\phantom{x^2}+b  $


\sbox0{$x^2$}

$a+\makebox[\wd0]{$0$}+b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks -- useful to me even if it doesn't work in MathJax.

Comment: MathJax doesn't support TeX Box arithmetic though

Answer (score 1):

Aha, the use of `\rlap` and `\llap` worked for me for left- and right-justified content:

```
a+\phantom{x^2}\llap{0}+b
```

I don't know how to get centered context but I can relax that requirement if I have to.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to easily get centered alignment this way. However, for the record, I think the 0 in this equation system looks best when it is right-aligned, and your answer would thus be the best to that end.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this won't work in MathJax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}

\begin{document}

$a+x^2+b $

$a+\phantom{x^2}+b  $

$a+\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle x^2$}]{0}+b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `eqparbox` package: it defines tagged box commands so a tagged box has the width of the widest contents in boxes sharing the same tag (requires two compilations):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

$a+\eqmathbox[M]{x^2}+b $

 $ a+\eqmathbox[M]{0}+b $

\end{document}
```

[image]